# How to Store a BluetoothDevice Object to Shared Preferences in my flutter App( BluetoothDevice object type not supported)

Tags: flutter, dart, android-bluetooth

My flutter app is using the  flutter_bluetooth_basic: ^0.1.5 and blue_thermal_printer: ^1.1.1 packages to connect to a Bluetooth printer and print receipts, but my problem is I want users to be able to connect to a Bluetooth printer and have it saved under shared preferences so every time they open the login, my app will try to connect to the Bluetooth printer automatically so they don't have to connect every time but have a Bluetooth device saved, but when trying to save it to shared preferences, I cant set it because it doesn't support the type of BluetoothDevice, how can save BluetoothDevive objects locally? any thoughts, please

Answer (score 1):

You can encode that object to a string then save it, and whenever you want it back just restore that string and decode it to you the original type
[here](https://medium.com/better-programming/flutter-how-to-save-objects-in-sharedpreferences-b7880d0ee2e4) is a full documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. Hopefully this helps someone with the same problem.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

setDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    prefs.setString("bluetooth", jsonEncode(device.toMap()));
  }

  BluetoothDevice getDevice() {
    String device = prefs.getString("bluetooth");
    if (device != null && device.length > 0) {
      var map = jsonDecode(device);
      BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = new BluetoothDevice.fromMap(map);
      return bluetoothDevice;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```